# Printing ClusterID and its elements using Spark KMeans algo.

Tags: apache-spark, k-means, apache-spark-mllib

I have this program which prints the MSSE of Kmeans algorithm on apache-spark.  There are 20 clusters generated. I am trying to print the clusterID and the elements that got assigned to respective clusterID. How do i loop over the clusterID to print the elements.

Thank you guys!!

```
           val sc = new SparkContext("local", "KMeansExample","/usr/local/spark/", List("target/scala-2.10/kmeans_2.10-1.0.jar"))
            // Load and parse the data
            val data = sc.textFile("kmeans.csv")
         val parsedData = data.map( s => Vectors.dense(s.split(',').map(_.toDouble)))

        // Cluster the data into two classes using KMeans
        val numIterations = 20
        val numClusters = 20
        val clusters = KMeans.train(parsedData, numClusters, numIterations)
        val clusterCenters = clusters.clusterCenters map (_.toArray)
        println("The Cluster Centers are = " + clusterCenters)
        // Evaluate clustering by computing Within Set Sum of Squared Errors
        val WSSSE = clusters.computeCost(parsedData)
        println("Within Set Sum of Squared Errors = " + WSSSE)
```

Answer (score 3):

as I know you should run predict for each elements.

```
    KMeansModel clusters = KMeans.train(parsedData.rdd(), numClusters, numIterations);

    List<Vector> vectors = parsedData.collect();
    for(Vector vector: vectors){
        System.out.println("cluster "+clusters.predict(vector) +" "+vector.toString());
    }
```