# Spark MLLib Kmeans from dataframe, and back again

Tags: apache-spark, k-means

I aim to apply a kmeans clustering algorithm to a very large data set using Spark (1.3.1) MLLib. I have called the data from an HDFS using a hiveContext from Spark, and would eventually like to put it back there that way - in this format

```
    |I.D     |cluster |
    ===================
    |546     |2       |
    |6534    |4       |
    |236     |5       |
    |875     |2       |
```

I have ran the following code, where "data" is a dataframe of doubles, and an ID for the first column.

```
    val parsedData = data.rdd.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.getDouble(1),s.getDouble(2))).cache()
    val clusters = KMeans.train(parsedData, 3, 20)
```

This runs successfully, I'm stuck now mapping the clusters back to their respective IDs, in a dataframe as described above. I can convert it to a datframe with:

```
    sc.makeRDD(clusters.predict(parsedData).toArray()).toDF()
```

But that's as far as I've got. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26939281/printing-clusterid-and-its-elements-using-spark-kmeans-algo) is on the right track, and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28743313/extract-kmeans-cluster-information-using-apache-spark) I think is asking a similar question to mine.

I suspect the labeledPoint library is needed. Any comments,answers would be appreciated, cheers.

Edit: Just found [this](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/KMeans-Get-elements-for-a-cluster-id-tt19285.html) in the Spark userlist, looks promising

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I understand that you want to get DataFrame at the end. I see two possible solutions. I'd say that choosing between them is matter of taste.

### Create column from RDD

It's very easy to obtain pairs of ids and clusters in form of RDD:

```
val idPointRDD = data.rdd.map(s => (s.getInt(0), Vectors.dense(s.getDouble(1),s.getDouble(2)))).cache()
val clusters = KMeans.train(idPointRDD.map(_._2), 3, 20)
val clustersRDD = clusters.predict(idPointRDD.map(_._2))
val idClusterRDD = idPointRDD.map(_._1).zip(clustersRDD)
```

Then you create DataFrame from that

```
val idCluster = idClusterRDD.toDF("id", "cluster")
```

It works because map doesn't change order of the data in RDD, which is why you can just zip ids with results of prediction.

### Use UDF (User Defined Function)

Second method involves using `clusters.predict` method as UDF:

```
val bcClusters = sc.broadcast(clusters)
def predict(x: Double, y: Double): Int = {
    bcClusters.value.predict(Vectors.dense(x, y))
}
sqlContext.udf.register("predict", predict _)
```

Now we can use it to add predictions to data:

```
val idCluster = data.selectExpr("id", "predict(x, y) as cluster")
```

Keep in mind that Spark API doesn't allow UDF deregistration. This means that closure data will be kept in the memory.

### Wrong / unoptimal solutions

- <s>**Using clusters.predict without broadcasting**</s>

<s>It won't work in the distributed setup.</s> Edit: actually it will work, I was confused by [implementation of predict for RDD](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/clustering/KMeansModel.scala#L53), which uses broadcast.

- `sc.makeRDD(clusters.predict(parsedData).toArray()).toDF()`

`toArray` collects all data in the driver. This means that in distributed mode you will be copying cluster ids into one node.

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing something similar using pySpark. I'm guessing you could directly translate this to Scala as there is nothing python specific. myPointsWithID is my RDD with an ID for each point and the point represented as an array of values.

```
# Get an RDD of only the vectors representing the points to be clustered
points = myPointsWithID.map(lambda (id, point): point)
clusters = KMeans.train(points, 
                        100, 
                        maxIterations=100, 
                        runs=50,
                        initializationMode='random')

# For each point in the original RDD, replace the point with the
# ID of the cluster the point belongs to. 
clustersBC = sc.broadcast(clusters)
pointClusters = myPointsWithID.map(lambda (id, point): (id, clustersBC.value.predict(point)))
```

Answer (score 2):

From your code, I am assuming:

- `data` is a DataFrame with three columns (`label: Double`, `x1: Double`, and `x2: Double`)
- You want `KMeans.predict` to use `x1` and `x2` in order to make a cluster assignment `closestCluster: Int`
- The result dataframe should be of the form (`label: Double`, `closestCluster: Int`)

Here is simple example application with some toy data adhering to the assumed schema:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, udf}

case class DataRow(label: Double, x1: Double, x2: Double)
val data = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(Seq(
    DataRow(3, 1, 2),
    DataRow(5, 3, 4),
    DataRow(7, 5, 6),
    DataRow(6, 0, 0)
)))

val parsedData = data.rdd.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.getDouble(1),s.getDouble(2))).cache()
val clusters = KMeans.train(parsedData, 3, 20)
val t = udf { (x1: Double, x2: Double) => clusters.predict(Vectors.dense(x1, x2)) }
val result = data.select(col("label"), t(col("x1"), col("x2")))
```

The important part are the last two lines.

1. Creates a **UDF** (user-defined function) which can be directly applied to Dataframe columns (in this case, the two columns `x1` and `x2`).
2. Selects the `label` column along with the UDF applied to the `x1` and `x2` columns. Since the UDF will predict `closestCluster`, after this `result` will be a Dataframe consisting of (`label`, `closestCluster`)

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this code works for you:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering._

val rows = data.rdd.map(r => (r.getDouble(1),r.getDouble(2))).cache()
val vectors = rows.map(r => Vectors.dense(r._1, r._2))
val kMeansModel = KMeans.train(vectors, 3, 20)
val predictions = rows.map{r => (r._1, kMeansModel.predict(Vectors.dense(r._1, r._2)))}
val df = predictions.toDF("id", "cluster")
df.show
```