# how to keep records information when working in Mllib

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm working on a classification problem in which I have to use mllib library. The classification algorithms (let's say Logistic Regression) in mllib require an RDD[LabeledPoint]. A LabeledPoint has only two fields, a label and a feature vector. When doing the scoring (applying my trained model on the test set), my test instances have a few other fields that I'd like to keep. For example, a test instance looks like this `<id, field1, field2, label, features>`. When I create an RDD of LabeledPoint all the other fields (id,field1 and field2) are gone and I can't make the relation between my scored instance and the original one. How can I solved this issue. After the scoring, I need to know the ids' and the score/predicted_label.

This problem doesn't exist in ML as it uses DataFrame and I can simply add another column with the score to my original dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

A solution to your problem is that the `map` method of RDD retains order; therefore, you can use the `RDD.zip` method with the id's.

Here is an answer that shows the procedure

[Spark MLLib Kmeans from dataframe, and back again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31447141/spark-mllib-kmeans-from-dataframe-and-back-again)

It's very easy to obtain pairs of ids and clusters in form of RDD:

```scala
val idPointRDD = data.rdd.map(s => (s.getInt(0),
     Vectors.dense(s.getDouble(1),s.getDouble(2)))).cache()
val clusters = KMeans.train(idPointRDD.map(_._2), 3, 20)
val clustersRDD = clusters.predict(idPointRDD.map(_._2))
val idClusterRDD = idPointRDD.map(_._1).zip(clustersRDD)
```

Then you create DataFrame from that

```scala
val idCluster = idClusterRDD.toDF("id", "cluster")
```

> It works because map doesn't change order of the data in RDD, which is
>   why you can just zip ids with results of prediction.