# how to keep records information when working in ML

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am basing this question on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38001318/how-to-keep-records-information-when-working-in-mllib) one. The OP says 'This problem doesn't exist in ML as it uses DataFrame and I can simply add another column with the score to my original dataframe.' Can anyone tell me how to do this?
I have tried:

```
val labeledData = data1.select("labels","hash-tfidf").rdd.map { row =>
  LabeledPoint(row.getAs[Double]("labels"), row.getAs[org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.SparseVector]("hash-tfidf"))
}

val scoreDF = model.transform(labeledData.toDS)

val dfPredictions = data1.withColumn("prediction", scoreDF.col("prediction"))
```

where data1 is my original dataframe with lots of columns.
This errors with:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: resolved attribute(s) prediction#1458 missing from ....[loads of fields I think from data1]...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `RDDs` and you don't need `LabeledPoint` and you cannot add column from another `DataFrame`.

It is not clear what the `model` is, but I assume it's input column is `features` so you can either rename the column:

```
model.transform(data1.withColumnRenamed("hash-tfidf", "features"))
```

or configure `model` to accept `hash-tfidf` as input.