# Get Cluster_ID and the rest of table using Spark MLlib KMeans

Tags: scala, apache-spark, k-means

I have this dataset (I'm putting some a few rows):

```
11.97,1355,401
3.49,25579,12908
9.29,129186,10882
28.73,10153,22356
3.69,22872,9798
13.49,160371,2911
24.36,106764,867
3.99,163670,16397
19.64,132547,401
```

And I'm trying to assign all this rows to 4 clusters using K-Means. For that I'm using the code that I see in this post: [Spark MLLib Kmeans from dataframe, and back again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31447141/spark-mllib-kmeans-from-dataframe-and-back-again)

```
val data = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/TESTE1")
val idPointRDD = data.map(s => (s(0), Vectors.dense(s(1).toInt,s(2).toInt))).cache()
val clusters = KMeans.train(idPointRDD.map(_._2), 4, 20)
val clustersRDD = clusters.predict(idPointRDD.map(_._2))
val idClusterRDD = idPointRDD.map(_._1).zip(clustersRDD)
val idCluster = idClusterRDD.toDF("purchase","id","product","cluster")
```

I'm getting this outputs:

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.{KMeans, KMeansModel}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.{KMeans, KMeansModel}

scala> import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors

scala> val data = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/TESTE")
data: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = /user/cloudera/TESTE MapPartitionsRDD[7] at textFile at <console>:29

scala> val idPointRDD = data.map(s => (s(0), Vectors.dense(s(1).toInt,s(2).toInt))).cache()
idPointRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Char, org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector)] = MapPartitionsRDD[8] at map at <console>:31
```

But when I run it I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Char is not supported
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:715)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Many thanks!

Comment: How do you execute this code ? In a spark-shell or an application ? Where and when do you see the error ? In your IDE, on compilation or execution?

Comment: @eliasah I'm running using Spark-Shell on Cloudera Vm. The error appears when I execute the last row of the code. I'm trying to get a dataframe with the three originals columns + the new column that indicates the cluster

Comment: Can you print out the content and type of idPointRdd from the shell ? Not what you suspect but the actual output.

Comment: @elisah I'm ve updated my post. Don't know if was that output that you are looking...

Comment: I wanted to ask you about the columns. Just to be clear. Your CSV contains 3 columns. The first one is a double and the second and third are integer ?

Comment: @eliasah the CSV will have 3 columns, the first will be Integer, the second integer and the third will be double :) And the third will be the price of the product and I'm trying to calculated the cluster by each price

Comment: The CSV you gave has a double in the first columns. e.g 11.97 is a double

Comment: @eliasah, sorry you're correct. First double, second int and third int

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127049/discussion-between-eliasah-and-joao-testesw).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the thing. You are actually reading a CSV of values into an RDD of String and not converting it properly to numeric values. Instead since a string is a collection of character when you call upon s(0) per example this actually works converts the `Char` value to an integer or a double but it's not what you are actually looking for.

You need to split your `val data : RDD[String]`

```
 val data : RDD[String] = ??? 
 val idPointRDD = data.map {
     s => 
      s.split(",") match { 
      case Array(x,y,z) => Vectors.dense(x.toDouble, Integer.parseInt(y).toDouble,Integer.parseInt(z).toDouble)
      }
 }.cache()
```

This should work for you !

Comment: @elisah the code works perfect! :) Only one more doubt why It predicts only two columns? I've put 3 columns at the beggining and it only allows me to cluster 2... I've updated the code

Comment: Because 'm getting this outptus: idCluster.take(10)
res2: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([11.97,1], [3.49,1], [9.29,2], [28.73,1], [3.69,1], [13.49,0], [24.36,2], [3.99,0], [19.64,2], [4.99,0])
And it don't make sense :)

Comment: According to the code you used before you were using 2 columns. Please re-edit your question for how it was before. This will create confusion since it's actually using the code my answer instead

Comment: Im in the supermarket now. I'll update my answer later

Comment: I have updated my answer to create a vector from 3 columns but that will not work with the rest of your code because it seems like you are using the first column as an id

Comment: many thanks! The intention was: Have three columns,Transaction_ID (in my sample the second column), Product_ID (third column) and Transaction_Value(first column). The main goal was to segment all the rows into 4 cluster(high-values, medium-high,medium-low and low). Since the main feature are the Value that's why I put it into First position. Is my thinking wrong?

Comment: Sorry but I'm having troubles understanding what you are saying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127043/discussion-between-eliasah-and-joao-testesw).